# Horizontal line has excess length in tabularx environment

Tags: tables, pdftex, tabularx

I am using tabularx environment to build a table, but I am getting excess horizontal line length in the right hand side as below:
[image]

My latex code looks like below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,citecolor=blue,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{geometry,tabularx,multirow}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{bookmark}
    \usepackage{gensymb}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} %This is the cause
    \begin{document}
    \newgeometry{right = 1.00in}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tabularx}{420pt}{|Y|Y|Y|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Event} & \textbf{Date} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

Please tell me how to eliminate this.

Comment: I do not get the behavior you have shown. But, then you did not provide a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) so perhaps there are packages that you are including or other settings that is causing the problem.  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me and does _not_ produce the excess horizontal lines. I suspect one of you  packages are out of date. I recommend you add `\listfiles` _just before_ `\begin{document}` and list the versions of the packages that appear in the log/console.

Comment: updating packages worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved updating the distribution.